# Identify connector

Tags: identification, connector

I tried really hard to find this online using all sorts of filters on various sites. Trying to identify this connector for LED strip modules.

4 pins, no latches (just flanges), 8.51 mm wide, 3.62 mm height.

[image: LED connector]

Comment: what's the pin spacing?

Comment: https://connectorbook.com/identification.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found and tested them: Mini Micro Jst 2.0 Ph 4 Pin

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01DUC1S7S?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DUC1S7S)

Comment: "and tested them". And what is the result of that test? Is it the correct one or not?

Comment: Yes, I tested them and they work perfect

Comment: Thank you. Then please click the "accept" icon next to the answer. (By the way, "Mini Micro Jst 2.0 Ph 4 Pin" is a made-up name from that vendor. That's not their real name.)

Answer (score 5):

The [pitch](https://forum.digikey.com/t/pitch-of-a-connector/172) appears to be 2 mm.

My [Identiconn utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_2&s=PH%20%2B%20PH%20PHN%20(crimp)) identifies it as a JST PHR-4.

Didgikey: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/PHR-4/608606

[image: JST PHR-4]

Source: [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/PHR-4/608606)

Other companies make it as well:

- Adam tech 2SH + 2CH
- Molex 89400 + 87369
- Sullins SWR201 + SWH201
- TE HPI-2
- Wurth WR-WTB 620

Comment: EDAC appears to make a clone under part number 140-504-210-011.